# ways to link in content of different sizes

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

i have the below xml cases

Case1:

```
<tertiaryie level="1">application filing, 11.112</tertiaryie>
```

Case 2:

```
<tertiaryie level="1">application filing, 1.112</tertiaryie>
```

and when i apply the below Regex.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(([Cc]hapter)\s(\d+))">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <a href="{concat('er:#AHK_CH_',regex-group(3))}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9])\.([0-9]+)">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
            <a
              href="{concat('er:#AHK_CH_',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'00'),'/P',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'00'),'-',regex-group(2))}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </a>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

THe outputs i get are as below.
Case1:

```
 application filing, 1<a href="er:#CHK_CH_01/P01-112">1.112</a>
```

Case2:

```
application filing, <a href="er:#CHK_CH_01/P01-112">1.112</a>
```

the regex is working fine for the second case, but not the first case. for first case, the number 1 is getting trimmed off and is coming before anchor tag. please let me know how to make the output as below. i need a template that checks either of the conditions and gives the output. And here the case 2 output is correct.

```
application filing, <a href="er:#CHK_CH_11/P11-112">11.112</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: i have re-tagged your question as `xslt-2.0` (instead of `xslt-1.0`) because of the use of the `<xsl:analyze-string>` instruction which is not available in xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply adjust your regex:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
```